# How to make this vertex follow this orientation?

Tags: transform-orientation

I have a vertex which has crossed over making an overlap. I want to make this vertex follow a specific angle. I tried to make custom transform orientation, I also tried with local, and also double <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> command. But it didn't work. How can I make it follow the red line perfectly.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a temporary edge by connecting your vertex to the one in the direction you wish to move(<kbd>f</kbd>), make custom transform orientation out of it and then delete it.

[image]

As Robin Betts pointed out you don't actually need to create the edge and if 2 vertices are selected, Blender will assume you want Transform orientation of an edge that would connect them. So apparently I did not need to create any of those tens of thousands of edges for them to get deleted after a second or two during my life not knowing this. :D

Transform orientations are made from normal orientation of whatever mesh elements are selected. You can turn on a transform gizmo when you are in Normal Transform Orientation mode and see the orientation of your selection:

[image]

Since I find it most useful to work with orientations of quad faces and edges, I think about it this way: Y is always along the longer side of a quad face or along the edge, X is always perpendicular to Y and tangential to surface, because it's also perpendicular to Z that is always pointing away from the surface in surface direction. With all other stuff it's usually enough for me to know the Z direction that is always pointing away from the surface.

Comment: Nice technique!

Comment: Just a side-note: you don't actually _have_ to create the temporary edge. The orientation can be created from 2 vertices.

Comment: That's really cool. I didn't know that. :D

Comment: (... same for 3 to define a plane).. what keystroke-display are you using? Or are those hand made? Very clear.

Comment: Yep, those are hand made. It's a bit annoying to make them.  I use  [ScreenToGif](https://www.screentogif.com/) I think it has some automatic way to show keystrokes as well, I don't remember why I decided not to use that anymore. I am sure there was some reason...

Comment: If you just want to move the vertex there's no need for a custom orientation. After creating the edge just press G twice to slide along the edge.

Comment: ah so the vector of the first selected vertex into the direction of the second vertex becomes the positive y-axis? when i press `G` `X` it's confusing how the *Transformation orientation* is done, it seems to point into a random direction. It would be useful to update the answer to explain what kind of xyz *Transformation orientation* is created.